# pasting two columns together in proper format in R

Tags: r, dataframe, paste

I have two columns that represent time, one for hour and one for the minute.  The data frame looks similar to this:

```
hr    mn
0     0
0     30
1     0
1     30
2     0
2     30
```

What I need is a way to paste these together to get one column `hrmn` that's:

```
hrmn
0
30
100
130
200
230
```

I thought this could be done some way using `paste0` but that gives me:

```
hrmn <- as.numeric(paste0(hr,mn))

hrmn
0 
30
10
130
20
230
```

Is there a way to paste these two columns together and get the format i need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df$hrmn <- df$hr*100 + df$mn
```

You need to check the class of columns `hr` and `mn`. Use `class(df$hr)` and `class(df$mn)`. If they are numeric, use:

```
df$hrmn <- df$hr*100 + df$mn
```

if they are characters. use:

```
df$hrmn <- as.numeric(df$hr*100) + as.numeric(df$mn)
```

Comment: That is a lot easier than I thought.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want to get an hour/minute format. You could do that with:

```
mydf$hrmn <- paste0(sprintf("%02.0f", mydf$hr),":",sprintf("%02.0f", mydf$mn))
```

which gives:

```
> mydf
  hr mn  hrmn
1  0  0 00:00
2  0 30 00:30
3  1  0 01:00
4  1 30 01:30
5  2  0 02:00
6  2 30 02:30
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `strptime` after `paste`ing the columns, change the `format` and convert to `numeric`.

```
as.numeric(format(strptime(do.call(paste, df1), format='%H %M'), '%H%M'))
#[1]   0  30 100 130 200 230
```